# How to get XMLElement value from a XML Document using C#

Tags: c#

**I want to get xmlelement from a xmldocument.**
*I did like this..in xmlelement elmDatatypes return null.*
"udds" is header tag name

```
       string a="<xmldata.its Like below image>";

        XmlDocument ObjReqDoc=new XmlDocument();
        ObjReqDoc.LoadXml(a);
        XmlElement elmDatatypes = ObjReqDoc.DocumentElement["udds"];
        foreach (XmlElement elmDatatype in elmDatatypes.ChildNodes)
        {
```

My XML data is
[image]

Comment: You need to add more detail. You can't just post code and expect someone to fix it for you.

Comment: you better put sample xml.

Answer (score 1):

string **a** should be with ".xml".
Try

```
File.Exist(a); 
Console.WriteLine("Path is ok");
```

Right under line with "string a=".

Sorry for "answer" I'm below 50 rep.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I g0t the answer Boguszm. Here no need to give header tag name. XmlElement elmDatatypes = ObjReqDoc.DocumentElement;Now its working fine.